# How to accurately sync time between iPhones?

Tags: iphone, time

I am writing an application that will require me to sync the time on a large number of iPhones accurately (to within a fraction of a second). As far as I can tell, access to the time function of the GPS is not available. If I sync over the Internet, then the biggest problem is network latency. The delay before the answer to a request is received can be estimated to be half the round trip - but how accurate can I expect this to be? Would it be worthwhile sending multiple requests and averaging or is there another better way of synchronising time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try implementing [Marzullo's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marzullo%27s_algorithm), as notably used in [NTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol).

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269532/network-time-protocol-for-iphone for information on implementing NTP on the iPhone

Comment: @David, Is this how Emerald Time does it?