# Get automatic date in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios

It is possible in iOS to change the date and the time manually. Now I use the date to validate the license of the application. Is there a way to get the automatic date and not set by the user. If it is not possible, can you suggest another way to achieve the same effect?

Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: Yep, get the time off the network somewhere.

Comment: You "validate the license"? Why do you need to do that? If you do an AppStore-App, you should rely on Apples licensing only, everything else is going to frustrate and confuse your users.

Comment: i'm registered at iOS Developer Enterprise Program

Comment: possible duplicate of [Network Time Protocol for iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269532/network-time-protocol-for-iphone)

Answer (score 1):

Use an NTP (network time protocol) remote service, but you'll have to implement a client for ios.

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in this question: [Network Time Protocol for iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269532/network-time-protocol-for-iphone)

More specifically, this is an open source wrapper for NTP:
http://code.google.com/p/ios-ntp/